# Cannot get attributes of nested SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Clearly I'm missing something simple.

I have the following xml string which I parse using simplexml_load_string:

```
$xmlString = '<root><Title>Heading Text</Title><Image><img src="https://image.com?id=123" alt="alt text" /></Image></root>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
```

However, I cannot access the img tag inside Image.

I would think I would use `$xml->Image[0]->img` to get the element and
`$xml->Image[0]->img['src']` to get the url of the image. But I keep getting the error:

> Trying to get property 'img' of non-object

`$xml->Image[0]` tests out as type SimpleXMLElement, and when I `print_r()` I get:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object (     
  [img] => SimpleXMLElement Object (             
    [@attributes] => Array (
       [src] => https://image.com?id=123
       [alt] => alt text 
    )          
  )  
)
```

Like I said, I know I'm missing something really obvious, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `echo $xml->Image->img['src'];`

Comment: @NigelRen That should be the same as `$xml->Image[0]->img['src']` shouldn't it?

Comment: @IMSoP, unsure what the actual problem is as they report getting the error `Trying to get property 'img' of non-object`.

Comment: @IMSoP, but isn't that also the basis of your answer?

Comment: @NigelRen I agree the question is unclear, but your comment is even more unclear. Are you saying "removing [0] will solve your problem" (false) "echo will solve your problem" (sort of true), or maybe just "try echo to debug" (helpful if you'd actually said it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, `$xml->Image[0]->img['src']` will give you the `src` attribute, but it will give it to you *as an object*.

If you run `print_r($xml->Image[0]->img['src']);` it will show you this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => https://image.com?id=123
)
```

But if you run `echo $xml->Image[0]->img['src'];` instead, it will give you this:

```
https://image.com?id=123
```

The reason is that [the SimpleXMLElement class](https://www.php.net/SimpleXMLElement) implements the magic overload method `__toString` (or its equivalent in internal C code), so that whenever you cast the object to string, it will give you the string contents. Since `echo` always needs a string, it does this implicitly, but you can do it explicitly with `(string)`, e.g.:

```
$imageSrc = (string)$xml->Image[0]->img['src'];
var_dump($imageSrc);
```

(As a side-note, the `[0]` is always optional - if you don't give a number, SimpleXML assumes you want the only or first child with that name, so `$xml->Image->img['src']`, `$xml->Image[0]->img['src']`, `$xml->Image->img[0]['src']` and `$xml->Image[0]->img[0]['src']` will all give the same result.)

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation. It made me realise that I'm not crazy.

The issue was that I was iterating through generated content and one of the times through the Image tag was missing the associated img. 

I added a test for that <duh>, and everything checks out.